# Square root of 2. Some mistakes that I've done C language

Tags: c

Yoo everyone, this is a code that fits my priorities, but the main problem is that he wrote not as much digits after the dot as I prefer to, but that much, which is divided by 4. F.E. 4 digits , after dot, 8, 12 16 20 etc. Where the hold up? Another question, how to read all symbols from a text book, it only reads one to array. Thanks for your time.

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

long B=10000000;
long LB=4;

void SetToInteger (long n, long *x, long Integer) {
  long i;
  for (i=1; i<n; i++) x[i] = 0;
  x[0] = Integer;
}

long IsZero (long n, long *x) {
  long i;
  for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    if (x[i])   return 0;
    return 1;
}

void Add (long n, long *x, long *y) {
  long carry=0, i;
  for (i=n-1; i>=0; i--) {
    x[i] += y[i]+carry;
    if (x[i]<B) carry = 0;
    else {
      carry = 1;
      x[i] -= B;
    }
  }
}

void Mul (long n, long *x, long q) {
  long carry = 0, xi, i;
  for (i=n-1; i>=0; i--) {
    xi  = x[i]*q;
    xi += carry;
    if (xi>=B) {
      carry = xi/B;
      xi -= (carry*B);
    }
    else
      carry = 0;
    x[i] = xi;
    }
}

void Div (long n, long *x, long d) {
  long carry=0, xi, q, i;
  for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    xi    = x[i]+carry*B;
    q     = xi/d;
    carry = xi-q*d;
    x[i]  = q;
  }
}

void Print (long n, long *x) {
  long i;
  printf ("%d.", x[0]);
  for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
    printf ("%.4d", x[i]);
    if (i%25==0) printf ("%8d\n", i*4);
  }
  printf ("\n");
}

int main () {
    char co[5000];
    char sym[5000] = "symboliai.txt";
    FILE* f = fopen (sym, "r");
    for (int i=0; !feof(f); i++)
    co[i] = fgetc(f); //1 symbol? (http://www.copypastecharacter.com/all-characters just deleted the numbers.)
    printf("%s",co);
    printf("digits?\n");
    int n=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (int a=0; a<strlen(co)-1;a++)
       if((co[a]!=n|| n>=0))
 {

 long NbDigits=n, size=1+NbDigits/LB;
  long *r2 = (long *)malloc(size*sizeof(long));
  long *uk = (long *)malloc(size*sizeof(long));
  long k=1;

  SetToInteger (size, r2, 1);
  SetToInteger (size, uk, 1);
  while (!IsZero(size, uk)) {
    Div (size, uk, 57122);
    Div (size, uk, 2*k);
    Mul (size, uk, 2*k-1);
    Add (size, r2, uk);
    k++;
  }
  Mul (size, r2, 239);
  Div (size, r2, 169);
  Print (size, r2);
  free (r2);
    free (uk);}
    else
        printf("skaicius neigiamas");
}
```

Comment: If you have two different questions, then post it as two different questions.

Comment: As for *one* of your problem, try to learn how to use a debugger. Then you can step through the code line by line to see what happens, while you can see what the values of all variables are.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're asking (at least one question) is how to print with higher precision.

To change how many decimal points are output to the screen, change the .4 in this to however many you want to print. The number before and after a decimal point in a print statement tells you how many digits will be output before and after the decimal point.:

`printf ("%.4d", x[i]);`

Be warned though you can only print as many decimal points as the value actually stores, the rest will be jibberish.

You're also printing decimal points after an integer type value (long) which makes no sense. I'm not sure what you wanted to do with this code and thus I'm not really sure what to suggest here other than this. Try doubles (%lf)?

Comment: tried it the problem is not here... if u change it, it does something like doubling the quality..

Comment: I'm really sorry but I don't understand what you're saying. It also looks like you're trying to print decimal places of an integer (long) which makes no sense. Could you please edit your question or comment or something and specify the exact issue you're having, preferably related to specific line/s of code.